# Connecting to a SMTP server with fsockopen from behing a proxy with PHP

Tags: php, proxy, smtp, fsockopen

I'm trying to connect to a external SMTP server from behind a proxy. I figured out how to let fsockopen get a website from behind a proxy, but not how to connect to a SMTP server. The SMTP server requires a TLS connection and username and password authentication.

What I have for getting a webpage from behind a proxy is the following code.

```
<?
$proxy_fp = fsockopen('111.111.111.111', '80');

if (!$proxy_fp) {
    return false;
}

fputs($proxy_fp, "GET http://wwww.google.com HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: 111.111.111.111\r\n\r\n");
while (!feof($proxy_fp)) {
    $proxy_cont .= fread($proxy_fp, 4096);
}
fclose($proxy_fp);
$proxy_cont = substr($proxy_cont, strpos($proxy_cont, "\r\n\r\n") + 4);
return $proxy_cont;
?>
```

Now how do I let the proxy connect to the SMTP server?

--- EDIT ---

```
<?
$s = "\r\n";

$proxy = '24.47.131.253';
$port = 8123;

$fp = fsockopen($proxy, $port);
socket_set_timeout($fp, 10, 0);

fputs($fp, "CONNECT smtp.domain.com:25 HTTP/1.0".$s.$s);

while(!feof($fp)){
    $line = fgets($fp, 4000);
    echo $line."\n";
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

I now have this based on the answers. The problem is that I don't get a response from the SMTP server, it just prints empty lines. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

SMTP and HTTP aren't mutually compatible protocols; in fact, they are completely different from each other.

What you could try is to use a loophole in the [HTTP CONNECT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_tunnel#HTTP_CONNECT_Tunneling) method: instead of GET or POST, send `CONNECT yourserver:yourport HTTP/1.0` - you should get a TCP connection to the requested host and port ([see this](http://www.web-cache.com/Writings/Internet-Drafts/draft-luotonen-web-proxy-tunneling-01.txt) for a more complete reference). Note that some proxies will limit the allowed destination port to 443 (HTTPS) or otherwise inspect the CONNECT traffic, to prevent people from tunneling to any service (e.g. SMTP).

Note that in most organizations, such actions might be interpreted as "circumventing access controls and/or security policy", so proceed with caution.

Comment: Yes you can, with the HTTP CONNECT method.

Comment: @user576875: Not reliably - CONNECT was implemented for forwarding HTTPS connections; using it for other protocols is unreliable at best.

Comment: It's not unreliable, it works like charm, even for SSH access. The only question is : does the firewall accept outbound SMTP connects. Because that will determine if it will work or not.

Comment: @wimvds: Hmm, interesting. Maybe the proxies where I tried were somehow blocking non-HTTPS traffic?

Comment: Well, to get through the firewall I just run SSH on port 443 (https). That should work on most (if not all) corporate firewalls.

Comment: @wimvds: That's clever. I've been trying something similar, but the proxy kept breaking the connection after tens of seconds. Edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Tijmen: Could you edit that into your question? Also, I think you should have a TCP connection to your SMTP server at this point; you'll need to do the handshake and protocol yourself though (see this for an example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol#SMTP_transport_example )

Comment: Edited in the question. I know I'll have to do the handshake, but I think the SMTP server should reply first on my CONNECT, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Tijmen: hmm, yes, you should see a `220` service ready greeting at that point. Do you get the same behavior if you try a CONNECT to a HTTP server?

Comment: When I try `fputs($fp, "CONNECT http://www.google.com:80 HTTP/1.0".$s.$s);` I get `HTTP/1.1 200 Tunnel established` like it suspected.

Comment: @Tijmen: And what do you get when connecting to the SMTP server directly, e.g. from outside?

Comment: `220 smtp.domain.com ESMTP MAIL Service ready at  Wed, 2 Feb 2011 06:21:25 -0800`